# Access to private or protected data of class with pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Suppose we have two functions (not any class member):

```
int input_int (int *p)
{
 p[0] = 10;
 return p[0];
}

char input_char (char *p)
{
 p[0] = 5;
 return p[0];
}
```

And some class:

```
class foo {
   public:
      foo();
      void some_usefull_stuff() {
           int i = input_int( &(this->A) );
      }
   protected:
      void feature_for_usefull_stuff() {
           char chr = input_char( &(this->B) );
      }
      int A;
   private:
      char B;
};
```

Will functions input_char and input_int work correctly? Won't they produce segmentation fault or any exception?

Comment: That's a pretty convoluted way for simply saying `int i = A;`

Comment: @jrok, perhaps that's because it's not? More like `int i = (A = 10)`.

Comment: Actually, it's saying `int i = (A = 10);`

Comment: @eg I should've added: "asumming A is initialized with some value"?

Comment: You don't need `this->` in the two places where it's used. And you don't need the parentheses in those wto places. `&A` and `&B` are all that's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will work correctly, the addresses passed to the methods are correct and point to the right types of data.

Comment: So, it just like I've assumed: all this class stuff is just like "syntax addon".
Thanks for help.

Comment: @user1644482 if by "class stuff" you mean access specifiers, yes. It's mostly there for the developer, but there are (even legal) ways around access specifiers.

Comment: Yes. I do not have toomuch experience with C++ so I still name "class stuff" only access specifiers. Thanks